# Background color and hover is not working for sticky column in scrollable HTML table. Also the table design is not cross browser consistent

Tags: html, css

I made this scrollable HTML table with left sticky column. The table row alternate color and hover is not working for this sticky column. For other columns they are working pretty fine.

Also the table layout is not cross browser consistent. In Firefox 54, the table design is absolutely fine. While in Edge and FF 70, there is a slight vertical alignment issue between stick column and rest of the table.

If we see the table in Chrome and Opera then it is totally screwed up.

So how to fix the background color and hover issue? And how we can make this table consistent in every browser?

Code:

```css
 #tb_wrapper {
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
  max-width:960px;
  margin:50px auto;
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
 }
 
 .tb_responsive {
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  margin-left:211px;
 }
 
 .tb_records {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
 }
 
 .tb_records th {
  background-color:#5F5F5F;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
 
 .tb_records th, .tb_records td {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  font-size:15px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow:-moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
 }
 
 .tb_records tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:#F2F2F2;
 }
 
 .tb_records tr:hover {
  background-color:#F5F5F5;
 }
 
 .sticky_col {
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  left:0;
  top:auto;
  margin-top:-23px;
 }
```

```html
    <div id="tb_wrapper">
     <div class="tb_responsive">
            <table class="tb_records">
                <tr>
                    <th class="sticky_col">Post ID</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">Post Name</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">Post URL</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">Post Title</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">Post Heading</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">Post Content</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">Post Date Published</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">Post Date Modified</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">Post Image</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">Post Views</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky_col">1</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky_col">2</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky_col">3</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky_col">4</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky_col">5</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky_col">6</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky_col">7</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky_col">8</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky_col">9</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky_col">10</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Layout issue in Chrome and Opera (The background color and hover issue persists in every browser):

[image]

In Edge and FF 70

[image]

Comment: Remove `margin-top:-23px` and also clear the cache of your browsers, by removing this only `1px` difference exist only in Firefox which is set by `top` auto to some `px`

Answer (score 0):

Make changes into .sticky_col class in css File.

```
.sticky_col {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    left:0;
    top:auto;       
}
```

Comment: No, I already tried this. Please check your solution in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code found in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/NethraDayalan/pen/YzKMKKr)

```js
// requires jquery library
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');   
 });
```

```css
.table-scroll {
 position:relative;
 max-width:600px;
 margin:auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
.table-wrap {
 width:100%;
 overflow:auto;
}
.table-scroll table {
 width:100%;
 margin:auto;
 border-collapse:separate;
 border-spacing:0;
}
.table-scroll th, .table-scroll td {
 padding:5px 10px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#fff;
 white-space:nowrap;
 vertical-align:top;
}
.table-scroll thead, .table-scroll tfoot {
 background:#f9f9f9;
}
.clone {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 pointer-events:none;
}
.clone th, .clone td {
 visibility:hidden
}
.clone td, .clone th {
 border-color:transparent
}
.clone tbody th {
 visibility:visible;
 color:red;
}
.clone .fixed-side {
 border:1px solid #000;
 background:#eee;
 visibility:visible;
}
.clone thead, .clone tfoot{background:transparent;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 6</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 7</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content<br>
            test</td>
          <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">&nbsp;</th>
          <td>Footer 2</td>
          <td>Footer 3</td>
          <td>Footer 4</td>
          <td>Footer 5</td>
          <td>Footer 6</td>
          <td>Footer 7</td>
          <td>Footer 8</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<p>See <a href="https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/LBrMxa" target="blank">position Sticky version </a>with no JS</p>
```

Comment: hope useful this link

Comment: NO, I already knew that. Not so useful. Create a clone of table and makes me difficult in my other functionality. I want to do and fix it with pure css without changing my existing layout.

Comment: remove `margin-top:-23px;` from `sticky_col ` class

Comment: No, I already tried this. Please check your solution in every browser.